# glxGetCurrentDisplay() is null (GLEW)

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I have just switched to linux mint and I am trying to get up and running with opengl on it. The problem is that the program has a segfault:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

int main(int, char*[])
{
    GLFWwindow *window = nullptr;

    if(!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout << "Failed glfw" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_TRUE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "Hey there", nullptr, nullptr);    

    if(window == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;  
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cout << "glew failed" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::vector<float> positions = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
         0.0f,  0.5f,
         0.5f, -0.5f
    };

    unsigned int vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    unsigned int vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positions.size() * sizeof(float), &positions[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); 

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), nullptr);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window) && glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);       

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, positions.size() / 2);        

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Running gdb on the executable led me to the conclusion that the context is not created properly:

```
3.3.0 NVIDIA 390.67

Breakpoint 1, main () at /home/alex/Desktop/misc/opengltest/main.cpp:35
35      if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
(gdb) step
glewInit () at /home/alex/Desktop/misc/opengltest/glew-cmake/src/glew.c:18012
18012     r = glewContextInit();
(gdb) n
18013     if ( r != 0 ) return r;
(gdb) n
18022     return glxewInit();
(gdb) step
glxewInit () at /home/alex/Desktop/misc/opengltest/glew-cmake/src/glew.c:17686
17686   {
(gdb) 
17692     display = glXGetCurrentDisplay();
(gdb) step

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

My gpu is an Nvidia Geforce GT630 and the driver:

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.67
```

I have searched numerous threads regarding context creation in opengl but I can't find anything that helps me. Note that the window is created, but right after that the 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)
' error appears.

This is my CMakeLists.txt (GLFW examples run just fine):

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.5 )

project( OpenGLTest )

find_package( OpenGL REQUIRED )

include_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/glfw/include/ )

add_subdirectory( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/glfw/ )
add_subdirectory( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/glew-cmake/build/cmake )

set( SRC_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp )

add_executable( ogltest ${SRC_FILES} )

target_link_libraries( ogltest ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} glew_s glfw )
```

So the question is: What causes this problem and what can I do about that?

EDIT: I am not really used to gdb but is this the correct use of bt command?

```
(gdb) n
35      if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt 4
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000004291f3 in glxewInit () at /home/alex/Desktop/misc/opengltest/glew-cmake/src/glew.c:17692
#2  0x000000000042a075 in glewInit () at /home/alex/Desktop/misc/opengltest/glew-cmake/src/glew.c:18022
#3  0x0000000000404335 in main () at /home/alex/Desktop/misc/opengltest/main.cpp:35
```

Comment: The 2nd line indicates that a function at address 0 was called. It looks like a function pointer was not properly set. (Initialization of anything failed?) I recommend to [edit] your question and show the complete stack trace. To find out more, it would probably be helpful to see from where 0 was actually called from. (In gdb, the resp. command is `bt` if I read this correct: [Examining the Stack](http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_7.html).)

Comment: Your question title is misleading. You already have successfully created a GL context, and the output of `glGet(GL_VERSION)` proves that. Your issue is with GLEW, particularily the gX part of GLEW.